# Group by under certain values

Tags: mysql

say I `GROUP BY` a `COUNT(*)`.

```
COUNT(*)        Value
3               200
7               200
10              20
15              80
21              100
30              200
33              400
36              300
37              100
```

I want to sum every other count above 30 into its own row.

```
COUNT(*)        Value
3               200
7               200
10              20
15              80
21              100
30              200
30+             800
```

Is it possible to achieve this without a subquery/querying the data twice in mysql?

Thanks!

EDIT : When I meant subquery, I meant subquery in the sense that there wasn't 2 'full' queries being done, this:

```
SELECT * FROM(SELECT *...)
```

is fine.

Comment: Can you provide a more plausible data set?

Comment: I think the data set was sufficient for the context of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN Count > 30 THEN '30+' ELSE Count END `COUNT(*)`, 
        SUM(Value) Value
FROM    TableName
GROUP   BY CASE WHEN Count > 30 THEN '30+' ELSE Count END
ORDER   BY Count
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/565111/3)

OUTPUT

```
╔══════════╦═══════╗
║ COUNT(*) ║ VALUE ║
╠══════════╬═══════╣
║ 3        ║   200 ║
║ 7        ║   200 ║
║ 10       ║    20 ║
║ 15       ║    80 ║
║ 21       ║   100 ║
║ 30       ║   200 ║
║ 30+      ║   800 ║
╚══════════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: That would only work if the COUNT(*) was actually a column, or at least the result of another query, and not the COUNT(*) result of the same query. (assuming that for simplicitys sake, the asker did not provide us with the entire query, hence his reference to the GROUP BY)

Comment: @TomCannaerts this can simply be change from `FROM    TableName` into `FROM (..subquery that calculates something...)`

Comment: Exactly my point. Doing this without a subquery or derived table (as was the question) simply isn't possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an IF() function on the result of the COUNT, but since that result is only available when the resultset is complete, that would require a subquery or at least a derived table.

```
SELECT t.somekey, SUM(IF(t.c > 30, 31, t.c)) As Cnt, SUM(t.s) As Value
FROM (
    SELECT somekey, COUNT(*) c, SUM(value) s
    FROM sometable
) as t
GROUP BY t.somekey
```

The result of this would be that everything larger than 30 would be grouped together as 31.